# Issue Creating Data Frame out of Columns Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use('ggplot')


df = pd.read_csv('time_series_covid_19_deaths_US.csv')
df = df.drop(['UID','iso2','iso3','code3','FIPS','Admin2','Combined_Key'],axis =1)
for name, values in df.iteritems():
    if '/' in name:
        df.drop([name],axis=1,inplace =True)
df2 = df.set_index(['Lat','Long_'])
print(df2.head())
lat = df2[df2["Lat"]]
print(lat)
long = df2[df2['Long_']]
```

Code is above. I got the data set from https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/novel-corona-virus-2019-dataset - using the US deaths.
[image: What it looks like]

I have attached an image of the output. I do not know what this error means.

Apologies if worded ambiguously / incorrectly, or if there is a preexisting answer somewhere

Comment: I think after setting `Lat` as index, `Lat` is no longer a regular column in the dataframe. We won't be able to successfully execute `df2["Lat"]`. You can find `Lat` in `df2.index`. Does that help?

Comment: Yep! Thank you - the issue was from indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define an index using one or more columns, e.g. via `set_index()`, these columns are promoted to index and by default no longer accessible using the `df[<colname>]` notation. This behavior can be changed with `set_index(..., drop=False)` but that's usually not necessary.

With the index in place, use `df.loc[]` to access single rows by their index value, aka *label*. Read about label-based indexing [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label).

To access the values of your MultiIndex as you would do with a column, you can use `df.index.get_level_values(<colname>).array` (or `.to_numpy()`). So in your case you could write:

```
lat = df2.index.get_level_values('Lat').array
print(lat)
long = df2.index.get_level_values('Long_').array
print(lat)
```

BTW: `read_csv()` has a useful `usecols` argument that lets you specify which columns to load (others will be ignored).